# Resize image with PIL and keep orientation

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I use the following commands to resize some JPGs:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(...)
im = im.resize(...)
im.save(...)
```

Some images that are shown on my screen in portrait orientation are after the resizing operation shown in landscape.

Is there a quick way to assure that the resized images have the same orientation as the original?

This is the full script that I use:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

final_size = 1200;

def resize_aspect_fit(dir):
    dirs = os.listdir(dir)
    print("resizing " + dir)
    for item in dirs:
         if item == 'resize.py':
             continue
         if item == 'resized':
             continue
         if os.path.isdir(dir + item):
             resize_aspect_fit(dir + item + "\\")
         elif os.path.isfile(dir + item):
             print("processing " + item)
             im = Image.open(dir + item)
             f, e = os.path.splitext(item)
             size = im.size
             ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
             new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
             im = im.resize(new_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
             if not os.path.isdir("resized\\" + dir):
                 os.makedirs("resized\\" + dir)             
             im.save("resized\\" + dir + f + '_%ipix.jpg'%final_size, 'JPEG', quality=90)
         else:
             print(dir + item + " not a file")

resize_aspect_fit(".\\")
```

Comment: Try `exif_transpose()` https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose

Comment: @MarkSetchell That works, thanks! Would you like to make it an answer such that I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it works for you. It's probably better if you write up exactly what you did, as you know better. Then you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkSetchell suggested in his comment, the `PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)` command does the trick:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps

im = Image.open(...)
im = im.resize(...)
im = ImageOps.exif_transpose(im)
im.save(...)
```

Comment: Well done - thank you for sharing back with the StackOverflow community.